# Actual download speed different from online speed test due to bad wiring

Tags: download, internet-connection, internet-speed, wiring

My internet company provides me with 10 MB/s download speed, but sometimes my faulty ethernet connector caps it at 1.1 MB/s. When I reconnect the rj45 connector (sometimes it takes a few tries) the bad connection is fixed and it goes back to 10 MB/s download speed.

The interesting part is, even when I have a bad connection and the download is limited to 1.1 MB/s, those internet speed test websites say I have a download speed of 10 MB/s. Why? And why is my download speed always limited to exactly 1.1 MB/s when I have a bad connection?

Comment: Is your internet connection supposed to be 10 MB/s or 10 Mbps? These are two different units and 10 Mbps = 1.25 MB/s which roughly matches your lower number.

Comment: Because your ISP provides 10 Mega **bit** per second, approximately 1.2 megabytes/s. ISPs very rarely measure in megabytes per second.

Comment: I'm sure we had some better duplicates but I can't find them at the moment...

Comment: The "bad connection" probably also forces the ethernet connection down to it's slowest speed, which coincidentally is also 10 megabits per second.